# replace special symbol in data frame in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, csv, replace

I have a dozen of big csv database which cannot be processed in Excel. These csv files have multiple variables which contains multiple empty values (empty values appear across multiple variables). But when I opened the csv file, these empty values were shown as underscore "_" which brought me some troubles when I tried to analyze the data in R. Therefore, I want to replace them with empty values. I searched all the relevant questions online but still could not solve it. I wonder if there is anybody could provide solutions which would not take so long to process in R.

Attached is the R code I currently use (but it doesn't work at all). I also tried `gsub` and `str_replace_all` but could not solve the problem or took hours to operate one csv. It involved with multiple variables which may not be the case for one variable situation since variables names may change across csv files.

```
text<-read.csv(dir[i],header=T,sep=",")
text[text=="_"]<-""
```

Comment: Are all of your variables text variables?

Comment: You can specify `na.strings="_"` when importing through `read.csv` which will replace them with `NA`, if that works for you.

Comment: Your code here works in a simple test: `test <- data.frame(a=c("A","B"),b=c("_","*")); test[test=="_"] <- ""`. It's not clear to me what your problem is, other than the possibility that perhaps you intend to be working with numbers, in which case `""` is insufficient, you will also need to use `as.numeric` on the number-like columns. (In _that_ case, @thelatemail's recommendation to use `na.strings=` is much better.)

Comment: Yes. So I want to collapse the data in R to calculate the average for each variable (except the category variable) but each variable contains "_" underscore. So it seems that the code read them as string first which could not give me the average number when I collapse them in R.